# Using worldpays lib to process cards, NSError when invalid card is used

Tags: swift, payment-gateway, worldpay

I am using Worldpays lib to process cards. I am trying to breakdown the NSError when an invalid card is used. It produces a response :

```
[Error Domain=com.worldpay.error Code=1 "Card Expiry is not valid" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Card Expiry is not valid}, Error Domain=com.worldpay.error Code=2 "Card Number is not valid" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Card Number is not valid}]
```

I cannot figure out how to get the "userinfo" from the returned object. I have tried:

```
print(response.0?["UserInfo"])
print(response.0?.description)



wp.createTokenWithName(onCard: ccName, cardNumber: ccNumber, expirationMonth: ccExpMonth, expirationYear: ccExpYear, cvc: ccCVC, success:{(code, response) in
            
            self.selectedToken = response!["token"] as! String?
            if self.isNewCard {
                self.transactionCall()
            } else {
                self.saveCardToAccount()
            }

        }, failure: {(response) in
            //TODO ERROR REPORTING
            print( (response.0).userInfo)
            print(response.0?.description)

        });
```

Comment: From where? What's the code? If it's `NSError` objects (array of them?), try in pseudo code: `(response.0 as NSError).userInfo` or `(response.0 as NSError).localizedDescription`